# Is there any function that draw a vertical line in a plot that has a lot of horizontal lines and the x axe is numpy datetime64

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I'm generating some plots with matplotlib, based on horizontal lines, i had trouble to make a vertical line.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.dates as dates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
import pandas as pd

# this part is where I set my axes

plt.hlines("A",'2019-07-16T03:30','2019-07-16T17:30',"white","dotted")
plt.hlines("B",'2019-07-16T03:30','2019-07-16T17:30',"white","dotted")
plt.hlines("C",'2019-07-16T03:30','2019-07-16T17:30',"white","dotted")

# Time axis
# définition des heures (axe abcises) axe majeur

myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator())    

# after that i import my data and make some treatment
# then i browse each one and plot just a horizontal line with :

plt.hlines("A",date1,date2)
plt.hlines("B",date3,date4)
# here i want to plot the vertical lines between those 2 hlines
```

I expect to make a vertical line that begins at the end of the first horizontal line and ends at the beginning of second one.

Comment: [`plt.vlines()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.vlines.html)?

Comment: I know the function but I'm dealing with datetime64 
vlines requires one axe like :
plt.vlines("A",date2,date3)
can u see it?
because I want to make a line between 2 horizontal lines with different axes